# PyTorch | getting "RuntimeError: Found dtype Long but expected Float" with dataset Omniglot

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Im a real newbie on PyTorch and Neural Networks. I have started to work on these suubjects this week and my mentor has gave me a code and with some tasks to work on the code.
But the code that he gave me is not working. I have tried to fix this all day but got no result. Because i do not know the background of the NN's and PyTorch it is harder to understand the problem.
Need your help on that.
Thank you !

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchsummary import summary
#DEFINE YOUR DEVICE
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device) #if cpu, go Runtime-> Change runtime type-> Hardware accelerator GPU -> Save -> Redo previous steps
#DOWNLOAD DATASET
train_data = datasets.Omniglot('./data', background=True, download = True, transform = transforms.ToTensor())
test_data = datasets.Omniglot('./data',background = False, download = True, transform = transforms.ToTensor())
#DEFINE DATA GENERATOR
batch_size = 50
train_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)
test_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
#DEFINE NEURAL NETWORK MODEL
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 8, kernel_size = 4, stride = 1)
    self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size = 4, stride = 1)
    self.mpool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(18432, 256)
    self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(256, 64)
    self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 50)
    self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
    self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
  def forward(self, x):
    hidden = self.mpool(self.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    hidden = self.mpool(self.relu(self.conv2(hidden)))
    hidden = hidden.view(-1,18432)
    hidden = self.relu(self.fc1(hidden))
    hidden = self.relu(self.fc2(hidden))
    output = self.fc3(hidden)
    return output
# CREATE MODEL
model = CNN()
model.to(device)
summary(model, (1, 105, 105))
# DEFINE LOSS FUNCTION AND OPTIMIZER
learning_rate = 0.001
loss_fun = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
# TRAIN THE MODEL
model.train()
epoch = 10
num_of_batch = np.int(len(train_generator.dataset) / batch_size)
loss_values = np.zeros(epoch * num_of_batch)
for i in range(epoch):
      for batch_idx, (x_train, y_train) in enumerate(train_generator):
          x_train, y_train = x_train.to(device), y_train.to(device)
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          y_pred = model(x_train)
          loss = loss_fun(y_pred, y_train)
          loss_values[num_of_batch * i + batch_idx] = loss.item()
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
          if (batch_idx + 1) % batch_size == 0:
              print('Epoch: {}/{} [Batch: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                  i + 1, epoch, (batch_idx + 1) * len(x_train), len(train_generator.dataset),
                  100. * (batch_idx + 1) / len(train_generator), loss.item()))
#PLOT THE LEARNING CURVE
iterations = np.linspace(0,epoch,num_of_batch*epoch)
plt.plot(iterations, loss_values)
plt.title('Learning Curve')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.grid('on')
#TEST THE MODEL
model.eval()
correct=0
total=0
for x_val, y_val in test_generator:
  x_val = x_val.to(device)
  y_val = y_val.to(device)
  output = model(x_val)
  y_pred = output.argmax(dim=1)
  for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
    if y_val[i]==y_pred[i]:
      correct += 1
    total +=1
print('Validation accuracy: %.2f%%' %((100*correct)//(total)))
```

Here is the error code that i receive.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:528: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([50])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([25, 50])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bffd863688df> in <module>()
     13     loss = loss_fun(y_pred, y_train)
     14     loss_values[num_of_batch*i+batch_idx] = loss.item()
---> 15     loss.backward()
     16     optimizer.step()
     17     if (batch_idx+1) % batch_size == 0:

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    150 
    151 

RuntimeError: Found dtype Long but expected Float
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't throw a different error? Already the `self.to(torch.LongTensor)` line in your initializer seems peculiar.

Comment: @Ivan Yes the 'self.to(torch.LongTensor)' line was experimental i did not run it, edited the post now. Also i receive the error code 'UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([50])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([25, 50])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size' as i posted in error code part.

Comment: Ok, could you print out the data type of `y_train` (via `y_train.dtype`)?

Comment: I received  the format ""torch.int64""

Answer (score 6):

Your dataset is returning integers for your labels, you should cast them to floating points. One way of solving it is to do:

```
loss = loss_fun(y_pred, y_train.float())
```

Comment: Yes, it has worked for our problem. Thank you very much. Drammatically the other problem has still there and the code has stopped while running the training part.

Comment: ///// UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([30])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([15, 50])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (50) must match the size of tensor b (30) at non-singleton dimension 1 ///////    This is the error code that i received

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15VIhurlZTYLz0mO-pgrEp3WA1MatE5Tb?usp=sharing#scrollTo=DEuX6ORhJL6Z   Here is the raw collab link

Comment: Your target tensor must have the same shape as the output of your model. You can do so by adding one extra dimension on `y_train`, and expanding it. For short, you should call `loss_fun(y_pred, y[None].expand_as(y_pred).float())`.

Comment: I have called the '**loss_fun(y_pred, y_train[15].expand_as(y_pred).float()**' inside and also out of my for loop and i still obtain the same error. Should i try the code in another way ?

Comment: I have tried anyway but it is not working because we have not any **"y"** defined so ? I mean the **y[None]** part

Comment: My bad it should be  `loss_fun(y_pred, y_train[None].expand_as(y_pred).float())`.

Comment: Yes i have tried it too but i receive the same error code that i commented. It takes the first batch clearly and finishes the first epoch but then the code breaks with the error.

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question with the updated code and error message?